# Error when accessing variable from another class

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a variable from another class. however, it shows an error at the following code:

```
public class ItemDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String[] args) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_detail);
      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      DummyContent Position = new DummyContent();
      int picCheck = Position.getPos();
    }
}
```

Here is the getter:

```
public int getPos(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Can you show me what my problem here is?

The error:

> Error:(31, 32) error: method getPos in class DummyContent cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: int
>
> found: no arguments
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: *Every* question which includes "it shows an error" or similar needs to say *what the error is*. Note that your code would be more readable if you'd follow Java naming conventions - a variable should start with a lower case letter, e.g. `position` instead of `Position`.

Comment: It's also bad practice to start a variable name with a capital letter, as this is normally reserved for class names. Change `DummyContent Position` to `DummyContent position`

Comment: Why does you "getter" -- as you call it -- take a parameter (and why do you immediately return that parameter)? It's not _getting_ anything, just echoing. Presumably the error is that you're not passing anything into your getter (you shouldn't be, it's the getter that's wrong).

Comment: I'm very inexperienced in java, and i just need to pass that parameter to another class, is there something else i should be doing?

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
int picCheck = Position.getPos();
```

Intending to use:

```
public int getPos(int position)
```

Notice that one line wants an int parameter; and that the other line doesn't give one.

And the **real** answer here is: the compiler message already tells you so. `Required int, found: no arguments`.

Meaning: java compiler messages are easy to read most of the time.

Thus the answer beyond the simple left-over here: if your Java skills are on a level that makes it hard to understand such messages, you are most likely **overburdening** yourself at this point by trying to do Android programming.